# reading user input of class 'Date'

Tags: java

Hello I am new to JAVA and I have been searching the net for this and I couldn't find a solution.

So I am trying to read user input and store them in vector but one of them includes a Date input. Now, I created a class of name 'Date' so I have to use Date as the type, however i don't know what to put as nextLine or NextInt - in order to read.

```
public static void edit(){
      viewAll();
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
      int i;


      System.out.println("Enter the Animal Code you wish to edit:");
      String cd = in.nextLine();

      if (cd == code){

       System.out.print("What is the animal's type? "); 
        String type2 = in.nextLine();
        n.add(type2);

       System.out.print("Enter the animal's unique code - Format: (XXXX111)");
       String code2 = in.nextLine();
       n.add(code2);
       //unique
       //XXXX102
       System.out.print("Enter the animal's weight:" ); 
       int weight2 = in.nextInt();
       n.add(weight2);

       System.out.print("Enter the date that the animal was obtained on: (dd/mm/yyyy)");
       Date date2 = in.next();

       list.addAll(n);

       //use date class
       System.out.print("Enter the animal's room and section (location) in the park:");
       String location2 = in.nextLine();
       n.add(location2);



       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Changes have been saved");
       System.out.println();

     }
```

Comment: Java already has a class for `Date` types. Also, from Java 8+ the preferred format is using `java.time.LocalDate`. You'll need to read in the input as a `String` and parse it into a `Date` or `LocalDate` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import the libraries you need including date with:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

You can then take in the input as a String and convert it to Date by doing:

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    String dateString = in.nextLine();
    Date animalDate = formatter.parse(dateString);
```

You will not need to create a Date class and can just the java.util library.

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Never use `Date` class.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" )
```

## Details

The terrible `java.util.Date` class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Specifically, `java.time.Instant` replaces `Date`.

If you want a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

By default, the *java.time* classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when parsing/generating strings. For a date-only that would be YYYY-MM-DD.

```
String input = "2019-01-23" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
```

If you want to support other formats of input from your users, [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20DateTimeFormatter%20ofLocalizedDate&t=iphone&ia=web) to learn about the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class and its `ofLocalizedDate` method. Already covered many many times.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ).format( f ) ;
```

> 23 janv. 2019

Comment: Can you elaborate why `Date` is a terrible class? (besides being old)

Comment: @matanper A quick search of Stack Overflow will reveal that. Start with the name, `Date`, that actually holds a date *and* a time-of-day. Add on a `toString` method that tells a lie. Also consider that the class purports to represent a moment in UTC, yet has a time zone mysteriously buried within its source code that affects some behaviors but not all — and tack on a lack of getters/setters for that zone to make it even more fun. Stir in some awful design based on a poor understanding of OOP. Then top with a dollop of mutability. Drizzle on a lack of thread-safety.